# is there any alternative method for taking second order derivative in signals?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, optimization, signal-processing

Eg:

1.Z=1+i*5 (in quadratic form),

2.s(t)=Z*exp(i*w*t), (i'm multiplying two signals)

now, i want to take second order derivative, yes i know the usual way like this,
[Equation](https://terpconnect.umd.edu/~toh/spectrum/Differentiation.html)

but is there any other alternative form to find 2nd order derivative?,

and by doing that i want to extract my original signal ("z", which's given above ) does any one have idea about this ?

I tried this way it's worked but i want reduce it more complex.

After double derivative i will calculate instantaneous angular frequency like this `W=(mean((y'')^2)/mean((s(t))^2))` and i will get result as `I=2*mean[(s(t)*cos(w*t))]` and `I=-2*mean[(s(t)*sin(w*t))]` this both I and Q are our original signal `Z=1+i*5`

Comment: You would get answers more easily if instead of making us read a really long article, you would just explain what you mean by "the usual way".

Comment: @MattiP. no, you no need to read full article, i'm just referring only the equation of second order derivative **(y'')** by using this one can calculate the curvature of the signal. But how to find curvature of the signal without 2nd derivative of **"s(t)"**  and at the same time i want extract or demodulate my original signal **(Z)**, u got my question ?

Comment: So you have measured a signal, right? You have a time series, a long series of numbers? And you want to calculate the second time derivative of that?

Comment: If you have a time series, your derivatives will anyway be numeric and approximate, and you have to use the values of the time series to calculate the time derivative. The way you calculate it is called a stencil. In the article that you linked, one such stencil is described. Is there a reason why you don't want to use it?

Comment: @MattiP. yes u r right, i have the signal which is **s(t)=Zexp(iw*t)** this nothing but original signal **(Z)** and carrier signal, yes i have time series too, where `t=[(T/80)*i]`, i=0..M-1,M=512;

Comment: You can calculate the time derivative with a finite difference. Here are some stencils for that purpose: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficient

Comment: Also this you can read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five-point_stencil

Comment: So was there any particular reason why you don't want to use the normal three-point stencil, which you pointed out in the article?

Comment: @MattiP. yes i want avoid complexity of this derivative actually i want to do all this math operation in micro controller so it's more simple if the equation is less complex!

Comment: Well, I think the stencil in the article is the most simple one. Do you need to do the differentiation "live" or only after the measurements? Because if you do it live, you would have to use a backwards difference.

Comment: Yes i have to do it in live! i went through those wiki documents but it's only an approximation, instead of going for approximation if we find a simple way to extract that original signal it would be really good because for me the **(y'')** are more simple equation compare than that wiki documents. if u see **y''** it's just involves less complexity and i need to add few more points after double derivative

Comment: @MattiP. continuation of by previous comment....i will calculate _instantaneous angular frequency_ like this `W=(mean((y'')^2)/mean((s(t))^2))` and i will get result as `I=2*mean[(s(t)*cos(w*t))]` and `I=-2*mean[(s(t)*sin(w*t))]` this both `I` and `Q` are our original signal **Z**

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a time series of values $s_k$, there are two ways of approaching this.

1. Analytical method:
   If you **know exactly** that your signal is of the form
   $$
   s(t) = Ze^{i \omega t} = Z \cos{\omega t} + iZ \sin{\omega t}
   $$
   Then you can just calculate the derivative:
   $$
   \frac{d^2 s}{dt^2} = -Z\omega^2  e^{i\omega t} = -\omega^2 s(t)
   $$
   Or, in simple terms, you just have to multiply the original signal by $-\omega^2$. Then the second derivative $y$ in every point is
   $$
   y_k = -\omega^2 s_k
   $$
2. Approximate method:
   If you don't know that your signal is exactly of the mentioned form, you have to indirectly **measure** the second time derivative, by calculating it at each point. The most straightforward way is the finite difference method, and for live calculation you have to use the backwards difference. If we set the second derivative to be $y$ and use the first-order accurate backwards difference
   $$
   y_k \approx \frac{1}{\Delta t^2}\left(s_k - 2s_{k-1} + s_{k-2} \right)
   $$
   This method uses only the "history" of the signal ($s_{k-1}$ and $s_{k-2}$). It's rather simple but gives an approximate answer. In this equation, $\Delta t$ is the time step used.

Comment: It's absolutely working fine for derivative but after that i want i want calculate instantaneous angular frequency like this `W=(mean((y'')^2)/mean((s(t))^2))` and i will get result as `I=2*mean[(s(t)*cos(w*t))]` and `I=-2*mean[(s(t)*sin(w*t))]` this both I and Q are our original signal `Z=1+i*5`  and i found some way to replace sin and cosine terms. But is there any alternative way to find mean or maybe some other method to reconstruct our **Z**,

Comment: I think in general, if you want the frequency, you should take the Fourier transform of the signal.

Comment: I i'm aware of that but FT is more complected to do in MCU, can we go in the flow of `yk=-W^2*sk`, from this, is it possible to extract our original signal `Z=1+i*5` ?